# New records are saved in store, but show only after refresh of page

Tags: extjs, model, controller, store, records

this a Sencha code which I am supposed to fix, however I don't understand why after creating new records to a store, they don't show immediately, but, only after refresh(?). Below are the relevant pieces of code.

Thank you.

**Controller**

```
 click: function(button){
                var window = button.up('window');
                var form = window.down('form#formTemplateWindow');

                if(window.action == "add"){
                    if(form.isValid()){
                        var store = this.getDataViewList().getStore();
                        var zones = new Array();
                        Ext.each(form.zones, function(value, key){
                            zones.push(value.data.id);
                        });
                        var record = form.getValues();
                        record.zones = zones;
                        store.add(record);
                        store.sync();
                        button.up('window').close();
                    }
                }
```

**Model**

```
Ext.define("web.model.Template", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
fields: [
    'id',
    'name',
    'layout_id',
    {
        name: 'reg_date',
        type: 'date',
        dateReadFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        dateWriteFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    },{
        name: 'background',
        type: 'auto'
    },{
        name: 'color1',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'color2',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'url',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'degree',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'playlists',
        type: 'auto'
    },{
        name: 'zones',
        type: 'auto'
    }
]
```

});

**Store**

```
Ext.define("web.store.Template",{
extend:"Ext.data.Store",
autoSync: true,
autoLoad:false,
model:"web.model.Template",
proxy:{
    type:"rest",
    url:web.util.Config.TEMPLATE_URI,
    reader:{
        type:"json",
        root:"result"
    }
},

sorters: [
    {
        property: 'Name',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }
]
```

});

Comment: Try using `store.reload()` in the click function.

Comment: Well, It would be better ,if you code a create a working fiddle so that I can work on it because all the possible solutions are not working, so something is wrong with your code.

Comment: Please make a fiddle. Records added to the store should show immediately. I have dozens of grids and stores where this works like a charm. You have to be doing something fishy not shown here with your store (filters?).

Comment: What about `record.set('zones',zones);`? `record` is an Ext Model, and you have to set field values using the set method.

Answer (score 0):

The server has to respond accordingly with the newly created records.

Answer (score 0):

Use `store.insert(index,record)` method instead of `store.add(record)`.
this inserts Model instances into the Store at the given index and fires the add event as well

```
store.insert(0,record);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change autoLoad property false to true

**autoLoad:true**